# The web app showing "This website has been updated in the background"

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The message can be received in background well,  but the people in the foregrround will nit receive the message and just show  "This website has been updated in the background".

I used the code sample from the fcm documentation.

Index.html (skipped the init script)

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
   console.log('Message received. ', payload);
   notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
   notificationOptions = {
     body: payload.data.body,
     icon: payload.data.icon
   };

   var notification = new Notification(notificationTitle,notificationOptions); });
```

sw.js

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {

  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    badge: payload.data.badge
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Can anyone help?  THX!

Comment: this appears to be messaging from a webworker to the DOM/window? See [Channel Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API)

Comment: It is from service worker

Comment: that's what it looks like. ...now that I look closely, sw.js kinda gives it away, ...as in "service worker.js"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display messages from the service worker in your app, use the following.

In your sw.js, this is how you talk to your users/app instances:

```
self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clients) {
    clients.forEach(function(client) {
        client.postMessage({
            msg: "cached: " + event.request.url
        });
    });
});
```

Then in your index.html script, this is how you process the message:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  console.log("service worker " + event.data.msg);
  //you can do whatever you want now that you have this data in script.
});
```

Comment: I have the service worker running on my website right now. It displays the message correctly in the background. But there is conflict between the setBackgroundMessageHandler()  and onMessage()

Answer (score 0):

The topic is pretty old, but I'll leave my solution here in case someone would have this issue.

The explanation of this issue can be found in this article https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/handling-messages#wait_until

In a nutshell push event shouldn't get executed before the promise created by ​`self.registration.showNotification` is resolved.

Using `onBackgroundMessage` the way official fcm [docs offers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker) reveals the same problem. To understand why we can look at declaration of `onPush` function in [sw-listeners.ts](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/messaging/src/listeners/sw-listeners.ts#L99) and how this function is actually called in [register.ts](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/messaging/src/helpers/register.ts#L81) file. You can see that `onPush` is passed to `e.waitUntil` which means that push event doesn't get resolved before the promise returned by `onPush`:

```
self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    e.waitUntil(onPush(e, messaging as MessagingService));
});
```

however, when you look at how `onBackgroundMessageHandler` is called inside `onPush`, you'll see that the call doesn't return promise or something.

Solution I came to is like this:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients
            .matchAll({type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true})
            .then(windowClients => {
                let visibleClients = windowClients.some(client => client.visibilityState === 'visible' &&
                    // Ignore chrome-extension clients as that matches the background pages of extensions, which
                    // are always considered visible for some reason.
                    !client.url.startsWith('chrome-extension://'));

                if (!visibleClients) {
                    event.waitUntil(
                        self.registration.showNotification(data.data.title)
                    );
                }
            })
    );
});
```

Checking clients for visibility provides handling for background messages only; this check is taken from `onPush` function of the library.

Answer (score 0):

When you format your push notification message, your message should have a 'Notification' field. Otherwise, the service worker will just consider the message as an update.

```js
 const message = {
    token,
    notification: {
        title: 'Your title here',
        body: `Message here`,
    },
    data: {
        key: value...
    },
};

await admin.messaging().send(message);
```